# Why is my django /login url shows noting on website

Tags: python, django

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . views import *

urlpatterns=[
    path('',home,name='home'),
    path('<str:year>/',companies,name='company'),
    path('<str:year>/<str:company>',experience,name='experience'),
    path('login',loginUser,name='login'),
    path('logout',logoutUser,name='logout')
]
```

views.py

```
def loginUser(request):
    return render(request,'App/login.html',context={})
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Placemet Freak - SFIT</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Output
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMGZx.png)
It shows a blank page, all other urls are working properly

File Structure
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBaqT.png)

It always returns a blank page, it should return

## Login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `login/` it will match the `companies` view. Indeed, `'login'` is accepted by the `str` path converter, and thus that view will fire.

You can put the `login/` pattern first:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('login/', loginUser, name='login'),
    path('logout/', logoutUser, name='logout'),
    path('<str:year>/', companies, name='company'),
    path('<str:year>/<str:company>', experience, name='experience'),
]
```

but likely you want to make the `year` more specific, and only accept a sequence of digits:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('<int:year>/', companies, name='company'),
    path('<int:year>/<str:company>', experience, name='experience'),
    path('login/', loginUser, name='login'),
    path('logout/', logoutUser, name='logout'),
]
```